# Would installing a dual band antenna on a single band 2.4Hz router cause issues?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I plan to do a simple mod to my [Cisco E1200 like in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQ6smEPqYpM).
The router is a single band 2.4Hz router, I recently ordered a [dual band antenna](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DMHSODS) that I plan to solder on. Will the antennas extra band cause issues?

Comment: Wouldn't do anything the modem (i.e the 802.11 chip) has to support dual band also, which means you'll have a dual band antenna that only uses one band

Answer (score 1):

A dual-band antenna is typically not going to be as good at either band as a single-band antenna would be at the same price, size, etc., because the antenna designer can't optimize for both bands at the same time, so he has to "split the difference".

But if you've got an antenna you want to buy and you believe that it's really 9dBi @2.45GHz and you don't mind that you might be able to get a single band 2.4GHz 9dBi antenna for less money (or that's smaller), then go for it.

It's not like it's going to pick up extra interference or "leak transmit power out the wrong band" or something. Antennas don't work like that. If it's 9dBi in the band you care about, it's 9dBi. It doesn't matter that it happens to also have decent performance in other bands you don't care about.